# What is a suitable job title for someone responsible for creating large data sets?

Tags: job, data

I write and record hundreds of sentences and format them in a way so they're ready to be fed into an AI model used in a chat bot. What job title would you consider this to be?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please [edit] your question to elaborate why you want to know this. Otherwise it is very difficult for us to help you. Moreover, your question does not appear to be related to academia, so please beware that it may be off-topic here.

Comment: "Data entry clerk"

Comment: Have you checked your contract for this information?

Comment: Who do you want to tell/impress with the Job title?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a "data curator."

[This paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/libr/69/2/article-p89.xml) indicates that US participants consider a data curator as one overseeing the entire data management cycle, while their European/Australian counterparts have a narrower view focused on technical aspects of archiving in the final stages of the data cycle.

Below is an excerpt:

> The use of the term data curator and its broad understanding was quite prevalent among the US professionals, while Australian and European participants made a clear distinction between data curators and data managers and did not use the terms interchangeably.
>
> Participant P stated: "Data manager is for the first part of the data life cycle and data curator is in the last part of it. The data curator reviews, migrates, and enhances data and metadata, whereas the data manager helps with data collection, metadata standards, and creating coherent and authentic data sets (that ideally subsequently need less curation). A data curator rather works with the final data objects, to optimize them to a final version that can’t be manipulated anymore after that.

Comment: +1. To me, at least, "data curator" implies that at least a bit of scientific judgment and research expertise was used. In contrast, a researcher could hire someone to do the "grunt work" of transcribing and recording (without knowing anything about the research goals); I might call this person a "lab assistant" or "clerk" or "transcriptionist" or something along those lines.